# No waiting while Truncate Table

Tags: sql, ssis

I have an SSIS package that runs repeatedly after 1 hour. This package first truncates a table and then populate that table with new data. And this process takes 15-20 minutes. When this package runs, data is not available to the users. So they have to wait until package runs completely. Is there any way to handle this situation so users don't have to wait?

Comment: And what should happen in the mean time? Deliver unfinished data? You need to give more detail.

Comment: Yes, We can deliver unfinished data.

Answer (score 2):

Do not truncate the table. Instead, add a audit column with date data type, partition the table with hourly partitions on this audit column, drop the old partition once the new partition is loaded with new data.

Make sure the users query are directed to the proper partition with the help of the audit column

Answer (score 1):

You can do an 'A-B flip'.

Instead of truncating the client-facing table and reloading it, you could use two tables to do the job.

For example, if the table in question is called ACCOUNT:

1. Load the data to a table called STG_ACCOUNT
2. Rename ACCOUNT to ACCOUNT_OLD
3. Rename STG_ACCOUNT to ACCOUNT
4. Rename ACCOUNT_OLD to STG_ACCOUNT

By doing this, you minimize the amount of time the users have an empty table.

Answer (score 1):

It's very dangerous practice but you can change isolation levels of your transactions (I mean users queries) from ReadCommitted/Serializable to ReadUncommitted. But the behavior of this queries is very hard to predict. If your table is under using of SSIS package (insert/delete/update) and end users do some uncommitted reads (like SELECT * FROM Table1 WITH (NOLOCK) ), some rows can be counted several times or missed.

If users want to read only 'new-hour-data' you can try to change isolation levels to 'dirty read', but be careful!

If they can work with data from previous hour, the best solution is described by Arnab, but partitions are available only in Enterprise edition. Use rename in another SQL Server editions as Zak said.

[Updated] If the main lag (tens of minutes, as you said) is caused by complex calculations (and NOT because of amount of loaded rows!), you can use another table like a buffer. Store there several rows (hundreds, thousands etc.) and then reload them to the main table. So new data will be available in portions without 'dirty read' tricks.